# DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a new file and write binary in it but the below error occurred

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\user\Documents...\bin\Debug\data\binary\admin.bin'.

Here is my code

```
    Dim bw As BinaryWriter
    dim pathBin As String = Application.StartupPath & "\binary"
    Dim fileExist As Boolean

    Try
        bw = New BinaryWriter(New FileStream(pathBin & "\admin.bin", FileMode.create))
        fileExist = True
    Catch ex As IOException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & vbNewLine & "Cannot create file.")
    End Try
    bw.Close()
```

Comment: does the folder binary exist? If not FIleStream will not create it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the path you are using does not exist which will make `FileStream` quite upset. Try something like this **before** you use the `FileStream`:

```
If Not Directory.Exists(pathBin) Then
    Directory.CreateDirectory(pathBin)
End If
```

This will ensure that if the directory does not exist then it is created ahead of time.